# lein re-frame template - No :main namespace specified in project.clj

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, re-frame

I have followed the readme from the `lein new re-frame <project-name>`[template](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template) *exactly*, but I get the error:

`No :main namespace specified in project.clj.`

I know this is a well documented error, but when I add the line `:main  my-first-reframe-app.core` to my `project.clj` and a `-main` function to `core.cljs` namespace, the compiler throws a huge error when I use `lein dev`.

Why won't this template run out of the box for me, and how should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

/edit Nowadadays, as can be seen in the README of the downloaded template
Use:

```
lein watch
```

and navigate to http://localhost:8280/ to see the started shadow-cljs app in development mode.

Comment: Sorry - typo - I meant `lein dev`

Comment: Aha okay :). With `lein run` you happen to get the same error. No need to change anything on the project template. It should work out of the box with `lein dev`. Does the error also occur if you change nothing to the result of `lein new re-frame <project-name>` and run `lein dev`? If yes, what is your Java version `java -version`?